# Laravel 5.8 - in_array give me error : 'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function in Controller like this :

```
public function convert($id) {
        $project        = ProjectMaster::findOrFail($id);
        $items          = ProjectItem::all()->where('id_project_master', $id);
        $deliveryOrder  = ProjectDeliveryOrder::where('id_project', $id)->first();
        $itemsDO        = ProjectItemDeliveryOrder::all()->where('id_deliveryorder', $deliveryOrder->id)->pluck('id_item')->toArray();

        return view('delivery-order-form-add', compact('project', 'value', 'items', 'itemsDO'));
    }
```

`$items` give me result :

```
{
"5": {
"id": 6,
"id_project_master": 6,
"name": "Item 1",
"qty": 2,
"cost": "1,000,000",
"totalcost": "2,000,000",
"rate": "2,000,000",
"totalrate": "4,000,000",
"created_at": "2020-01-24 03:23:25",
"updated_at": "2020-01-24 03:23:25"
},
   "6": {
       "id": 7,
       "id_project_master": 6,
       "name": "Item 2",
       "qty": 2,
       "cost": "2,500,000",
       "totalcost": "5,000,000",
       "rate": "4,000,000",
       "totalrate": "8,000,000",
       "created_at": "2020-01-24 03:23:25",
       "updated_at": "2020-01-24 03:23:25"
    }
}
```

and `$itemsDO` give me result :

```
[
6
]
```

Then I have a loop where in every loop, do validate if exist `in_array($this, $array)` in blade view like :

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
<tr>
    <td class="text-right"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="id_item[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" @if(in_array($item->id, $itemsDO)) disabled @endif></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

This validate give me an error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.
I write wrong parameter or `in_array` not working on blade Laravel?

Comment: could you change in_array($item->id, $itemsDO[0])) or if you will use foreach
usd foreach ($items as $key=>$item) in_array($item->id, $itemsDO[$key]))

Comment: @Salemloress I tried with increment $key index of array, still give me same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this code :

```
<td class="text-right"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="id_item[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" @if(in_array($items[$i]->id, $itemsDO)) disabled @endif></td>
```

`$i` is loop increment

Answer (score 1):

Blade expects `@if` and `@endif` to be on individual line. You can use ternary IF instead:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
<tr>
    <td class="text-right"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="id_item[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" {{ (in_array($item->id, $itemsDO)) ?  "disabled" : "" }}></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `if` statement.

You should say if condition is true `echo` disable.In the way that you write `disable` is an `simple string` but you should introduce it as `html code`.

So in brief,you should call `disable` in `echo` function